# Create and execute a shell script in Linux home directory

Tags: linux, shell

I would like to create (and execute) a shell script in my home directory (/home/user).

Have tried the following:

```
printf "cd /mypath\n" > myShortcut.sh
chmod +x myShortcut.sh
sh myShortcut.sh
```

where am I going wrong?

(am trying to set up a shortcut to navigate to a different directory)

Comment: Nothing seems wrong here ... Script work in another shell instance forked by the main shell ..

Comment: Yes - I see where I went wrong now - have updated the question to show my ultimate intention, should have done this in the first place!

Comment: As an aside, you don't need to set the execute bit with `chmod` if you run the command as `sh myShortcut.sh` (or, as suggested in the answers, `source myShortcut.sh`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to execute the script in the **current shell** (as opposed to in a *subshell*), use the `source` (or `.`) command:

```
 source myShortcut.sh
```

This should then change the directory as expected.

In addition, sourcing also allows you to set and change environment variables in the current shell--a very frequent question in its own right :-)

Comment: this does not work for me :- cannot open [No such file or directory]

Comment: got it!! Need to type:  source ./myShortcut.sh

Answer (score 4):

What is exactly wrong here?  That you are still in /home/user after the script executes?  Well thats because executing the script creates a child shell that returns to the parent shell once the script ends.  Therefore your cd has NO EFFECT in your current shell.

Comment: That was exactly my conundrum.  +1 for the explanation

Answer (score 2):

That won't work because of what the other answer says. The script operates in a child shell.

For a shortcut like that, you could set up an alias, edit the .bashrc file in your home directory and add a line like

alias shortcut='cd /mypath'

Substitute "shortcut" for whatever you want to name it, and mypath to the path you want.
Restart the shell (close terminal and reopen or w/e) and that should work just as you want.
Then you can use "shortcut" anywhere you want in the shell.

Comment: "shortcut" or however you named the alias... substitute "shortcut", not alias

Comment: Thanks - have done this - so how do I 'use' the shortcut?  Have tried typing 'shortcut' (using my ref) straight into the shell but I get 'Not Found'..

Comment: remember to restart the shell, if it doesn't work you didn't put it in the right place